# $\lim_{x\to 0} \left| \frac{\int_0^x e^{-y2} dy}{x} \right|$

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to do $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \left| \frac{\int_0^x e^{-y^2}\mathrm dy}{x} \right|$. Is it legitimate to say

$$\lim_{x\to0} \left| \frac{\int_0^x e^{-y^2}\mathrm dy}{x} \right| \stackrel{\mathrm{L'H, \ FTC}} = \lim_{x\to0} \left| \frac{e^{-x^2}-e^0}{1} \right| = 0?$$

If not, why not? Thanks.

Comment: L'H means L'Hopital's Rule and FTC means Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Comment: By FTC, there is no $-e^0$ term. Also, technically you need to show the second limit exists before using L'H.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call

$$
F(x)=\int_0^{x}e^{-y^2}\,dy\;.
$$
Clearly $F(0)=0$.
Then
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\int_0^{x}e^{-y^2}\,dy}{x}
= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0}
=F'(0)=1
$$

since FTC implies $F'(x)=e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: So I'm wrong in using L'Hopital's here?

Comment: You are not, but you are using FTC wrong.

Comment: @jeremy909 First you must justify taking the limit inside modulus. This is because "modulus" is a continuous function. While applying LH and while differentiating the numerator using differentiation under integral sign, the formula has been wrongly applied. The differentiation of the lower limit 0 gives 0 and hence the second term will be zero and not e^0.

Answer (score 2):

Use L-Hospital Rule and Lebnitz
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{x} e^{-y^2} dy}{x}= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{1}=1 .$$
Note that $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-y^2} dy=1. e^{-x^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Set $f(x)=x^2-\left(1-e^{-x^2}\right)$ then $f'(x)=2x\left(1-e^{-x^2}\right)\ge 0$ for $x\in\mathbb R^+$.

Since $f(0)=0$ and $f\nearrow$ we conclude that $(1-e^{-x^2})\le x^2$

Thus $\displaystyle 0\le\frac 1x\int_0^x \left(1-e^{-t^2}\right)\mathop{dt}\le \frac 1x\int_0^x t^2\mathop{dt}=\frac{x^3}{3x}=\frac 13x^2\to 0\quad$ when $x\to 0$.

And we have our conclusion $$\frac 1x\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\mathop{dt}\sim\frac 1x\int_0^x 1\mathop{dt}=1$$

---

More quickly we could also just integrate the Taylor expansion:

$\displaystyle \frac 1x\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\mathop{dt}=\frac 1x\int_0^x (1+o(1))\mathop{dt}=\frac 1x(x+o(x))=1+o(1)\to 1$

In fact this is just a shortcut to integrating the inequality $0\le 1-e^{-x^2}\le\varepsilon$ when $x\ll 1$.

Comment: Note, in the first case in only took $x>0$ into account, but it is trivial by parity for the negative side.