# Evaluate the limit of $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left ( \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} e^{t^{2}} dt \right )$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the limit of $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \left ( \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} e^{t^{2}} dt \right ) $$

Solution:
based on *Leibniz's Rule*,

$$ \require{cancel} \cancel{\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt = e^{x^{2}} - e^{0^{2}} + \int_{0}^{x} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} e^{t^{2}}\right) dt} $$

$$ \int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt = e^{x^{2}} - e^{0^{2}} + \int_{0}^{x} \left(\frac{\mathrm{∂}}{\mathrm{∂}x} e^{t^{2}}\right) dt $$

and, since it is ***dx***, can we treat ***t*** as a constant? So, $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} e^{t^{2}} = 0 $$

therefore we have,

$$ \frac{e^{x^{2}} - 1}{x}  $$

by apply *L'Hôpital's rule*,

$$ \frac{e^{x^{2}}2x - 0}{1} $$

so, when $x\rightarrow \infty$, the whole expression tends to infinity as well.

Comment: The step based on Leibnitz rule doesn’t make sense. You can directly apply Lhopitals rule instead

Comment: Or observe that $\int_{0}^{x} e^{t^{2}} dt>e^{(x-1)^2}$ if $x>1$.

Comment: @Integrand You have the wrong limiting value, so this is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: Exact same problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3822618/lim-x-to-0-left-frac-int-0x-e-y2-dyx-right/3822631#3822631

Comment: L'Hospital rule may be used here.

Comment: @Joe It is not the exact same problem, note that the limiting value is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f(t)=e^{t^2}$ is a positive function which grows 'very quickly' so that the area under the curve, $\int_0^x e^{t^2} \;dt$ should increase very quickly - much faster than that for a line. So we suspect the limit should be infinite. Let's try to make sense of this idea.

We know the first few terms of the Taylor Series for $f(t)= e^{t^2}$, namely $1+t^2 + O(t^4)$. [If you do not know this yet, do not worry.] So let's show that $e^{t^2}$ is always bigger than $g(t)= 1+t^2$ for $t \geq 1$. We know that $f(1)= e \approx 2.71828$ and $g(1)= 2$ so that $f(1)>g(1)$. Now $f'(t)= 2t e^{t^2}$ and $g'(t)= 2t$. But because $e>1$, we know that $f'(t)= 2te^{t^2}>2 t \cdot 1= 2t= g'(t)$. Therefore, $f(t) > g(t)$ for all $t \geq 1$.

Now because $f(t) \geq 0$, we know $\int_0^1 e^{t^2} \;dt \geq 0$. But then for $x>1$,
$$
\int_0^x e^{t^2} \;dt= \int_0^1 e^{t^2} \;dt + \int_1^x e^{t^2} \;dt \geq \int_1^x e^{t^2} \; dt
$$
Now we know that
$$
\int_1^x g(t) \;dt= \int_1^x (1+t^2) \;dt= \dfrac{x^3 + 3x-4}{3}
$$
But then we have
$$
\int_0^x e^{t^2} \;dt \geq \int_1^x (1+t^2) \;dt= \dfrac{x^3 + 3x-4}{3}
$$
But
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{x^3 + 3x-4}{3}}{x}= \infty
$$
This shows that
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{x} \int_0^x e^{t^2} \;dt= \infty
$$

Note: You can use l'Hopital's rule as well. My opting for the solution above is that with 'non-obvious' l'Hopital problems, students often forget to check the underlying assumptions for l'Hopitals and then either have an incomplete solution or an incorrect one. Open your textbook and check the assumptions for l'Hopital's for the functions $f(x)= \int_0^x e^{t^2} \;dt$ and $g(x)= x$. Then from the comments above, we know that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)= \infty$ and it is obvious that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)= \infty$. Then using l'Hopital's rule (and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for $f'(x)$), we have
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\int_0^x e^{t^2} \;dt}{x} \stackrel{\text{L.H.}}{=} \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x e^{t^2} \;dt}{\frac{d}{dx} x}= \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{e^{x^2}}{1}= \infty
$$